# Condition to check if variables exist in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

I have an array named `data` as shown below and an array of objects named `obj1`.

```
var data = ["004", "456", "333", "555"];


obj1 = [{
  id: "004",
  name: "Rick",
  Active: "false"
  }, {
    id: "005",
    name: 'david',
    Active: "false"
}];
```

I check if elements of array `data` are present in the `obj1`. This is the code for that. It will give that `"004"` as the answer as `004` is present in the `obj1`.

```
out = [];

_.each(arr, function(value1, key1, obj1) {
   _.each(data, function(value, key, obj) {
        if (value1.id == value) out.push(value);
   });
});

console.log(out);
```

Now i want the following to be added too

```
var Activecheck = false;
```

I want to check if elements of arrray `data` is present in `obj1` where the `obj1.Active` field is equal to false. Any way to add this variable into my code where I can check this condition?

Comment: `if (value1.id == value && value1.Active == false)` ?

Comment: You can filter your obj1 array with condition active = false. It will give you only object with active false. Use Array.filter, and then you can use Array.some to check if value exists in filtered array.

Comment: @Amir- The value 'Activecheck' can be true or false and it is dynamic in nature. hence i cannot directly put a condition of false.

Comment: `if (value1.id == value && value1.Active == Activecheck)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Array.filter might be cleaner, like so:

```
var activeCheck = "false";
var out = obj1.filter(function(item) {
  return item.active === activeCheck && data.includes(item.id);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

With underscore, use the [`_.filter` function](http://underscorejs.org/#filter):

```
var isActive = "false"; // get that value dynamically
var result = _.filter(obj1, function(value) {
  return data.indexOf(value.id) > -1 && value.Active === isActive;
});
```

```js
var data = ["004", "456", "333", "555"];


obj1 = [{
  id: "004",
  name: "Rick",
  Active: "false"
}, {
  id: "005",
  name: 'david',
  Active: "false"
}];

var result = _.filter(obj1, function(value) {
  return data.indexOf(value.id) > -1 && value.Active === "false";
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

A more generic way is to use [`_.where`](http://underscorejs.org/#where) to filter by any attributes, easily set in an object, which you can build dynamically:

```
var filters = { Active: "false" }; // add any attributes to filter more precisely

var filtered = _.where(obj1, filters);

var result = _.filter(filtered, function(value) {
  return data.indexOf(value.id) > -1;
});
```

```js
var data = ["004", "456", "333", "555"];


obj1 = [
  { id: "004", name: "Rick", Active: "false"}, 
  { id: "005", name: 'david', Active: "false"},
  { id: "456", name: "Steeve", Active: "false", test: 1}, 
];

var filters = { Active: "false", test: 1 };

var filtered = _.where(obj1, filters);

var result = _.filter(filtered, function(value) {
  return data.indexOf(value.id) > -1;
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

You can even [chain](http://underscorejs.org/#chain) calls:

```
var result = _.chain(obj1)
    .where({ Active: "false" })
    .filter(function(value) {
        return data.indexOf(value.id) > -1;
    })
    .value();
```

And as a function:

```
function filterWithData(obj, filters) {
    // if you want to filter (e.g. Active) by default
    // filters = _.extend({ Active: "false" }, filters);
    return _.chain(obj)
        .where(filters)
        .filter(function(value) {
            return data.indexOf(value.id) > -1;
        })
        .value();
}
```

Then use the function whenever you need it:

```
var result = filterWithData(obj1, { Active: "false" });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use filter and includes to achieve what you want.

```js
var data = ["004", "456", "333", "555"];


var obj1 = [{
  id: "004",
  name: "Rick",
  Active: "false"
}, {
  id: "005",
  name: 'david',
  Active: "false"
}];

var result = obj1.filter((ele, idx) => {
  return data.includes(ele.id) && ele.Active === "false";
});

console.log(result);
```